# Creating 2 tables - ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

I am trying to create 2 tables: Person and Friend.

In the Friends table, I have a composite primary foreign key that references personId from the Person Table.

Please note i'm trying to do this in Java (Eclipse IDE).

I keep getting this error when I'm trying to create the Friends table for some reason:

ORA-00904: : invalid identifier

```
  String createPersonalInformationTable = 
              "CREATE TABLE Persons("
            + "personId         INT NOT NULL, "
            + "email_userName   VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "
            + "password         VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "
            + "firstName        VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "
            + "midlleName       VARCHAR2(50), "
            + "lastName         VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "
            + "country          VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "
            + "city             VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "
            + "PRIMARY KEY (personId), "
            + "UNIQUE (email_userName)"
            + ")";

  String createFriendsTable =
          "CREATE TABLE Friends("
        + "personId     INT NOT NULL, "
        + "friendId     INT NOT NULL, "
        + "status       VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "
        + "PRIMARY KEY (personId, friendId), "
        + "FOREIGN KEY (personId) REFERENCES Persons(personId), "
        + "FOREIGN KEY (friendId) REFERENCES Persons(personId), "           
        + ")";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  String createFriendsTable =
          "CREATE TABLE Friends("
        + "personId     INT NOT NULL, "
        + "friendId     INT NOT NULL, "
        + "status       VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, "
        + "PRIMARY KEY (personId, friendId), "
        + "FOREIGN KEY (personId) REFERENCES Persons(personId), "
        + "FOREIGN KEY (friendId) REFERENCES Persons(personId), "           
                                                              ^
        + ")";
```

Extra trailing comma